# C# WinForm up down drag click

Tags: c#

How do I capture a left mouse click , up/down/drag? What would the right mouse click be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding OnMouseClick, OnMouseDown, or OnMouseUp would be the way to go.  The MouseEventArgs class can contains members which will help you figure out which button(s) were pressed.

Dragging is a different animal altogether.  You need to override the OnDragEnter and OnDragDrop methods, and you will also need to initiate the drag-drop operation by calling DoDragDrop at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void FormA_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
            }
        }
```